# Where can I find more info on Deployment model?

Tags: deployment

•Select a deployment model
This objective may include but is not limited to: identifying artifacts and execution appropriate for sandbox and farm (i.e. GAC vs. BIN) implementation, designing solutions for single server or multi-server environments, dividing artifacts between sandbox and farm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a good start is the patterns and practices for sharepoint by microsoft:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770300.aspx

another good option is to buy the book "[inside microsoft sharepoint 2010](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735627460)" written by [Andrew connel](http://www.andrewconnell.com/index.aspx), Ted Pattison and Scot Hillier of critical path training. I think that will give a good cover up.